# Is there a way to replace the web browser in steam?

Tags: steam

I would very much like a better web browser than the one currently in steam, and I know that I can run it without significant decline in performance.  I was wondering if there is a way to change it and if there is also a  way to embed a chat client as well.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Xfire](http://www.xfire.com/) and [PlayXpert](http://playxpert.com/web/guest/home) offer web browsers as part of their in-game overlays. There is also the [Rogue in-game browser](http://rogue.gotgame.com/). Xfire offer a [preview video](http://www.xfire.com/about_ingame_browser/) of their web browser. All look to have tabbed browsing and offer more features than Steam's, though it's hard for me to say whether they meet your expectations.

Both Xfire and PlayXpert also ship with chat clients.

[Raptr's](http://raptr.com/) in-game overlay supports AIM and I believe XChat makes available an addon to that end also. Personally I'd try Raptr first. Any of the web browsers may also support [AIM Express](http://www.aim.com/products/express), an official browser-based AIM client.

Comment: All I need is AIM so I don't have to actively lie to my girlfriend as to why I can't chat every time I play games :D

Comment: Also, Xfire is instead of Steam, not an add on, correct?

Comment: PlayXpert, on the other hand looks perfect.  I will have to try it out tomorrow.

Comment: @Mechko, yes, it would appear you have to choose between the Xfire and Steam overlays. I've updated my answer based on your interest in AIM.

Comment: Thank you very much.  it's now night here, and it is time to sleep, so I will try your solutions when I get a chance tomorrow evening.

Comment: @Mechko have you considered a netbook? I keep my netbook beside my main computer for reasons like this.

Comment: @Ricket: I have an iPod Touch which I use when it has batteries, but it isn't always charged.  A netbook, for $600 (the cheapest in Australia) is overkill for an in game chat accessory.  I will probably get a desktop when I return to the states, but I still need the solution for now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the rendering engine behind Xfire's and PlayXpert's overlay browsers? :/

Comment: AIM! haha this answer from 2010 is hardly relevant anymore but amusing to be reminded of ancient software like AOL. Lol!

Answer (score 7):

Steam uses a webkit-based browser, the same engine that is behind Chrome and Safari. It was chosen above Trident (IE technology) because of crossplatform compatibility (= it runs mostly unchanged on Mac OS X). At best of my knowledge, this cannot be changed.

Overlay chat is already available through Steam's social features. Although it's not very convenient, you can get access to many chat networks through [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat); for example, [`x.aim.com`](http://x.aim.com/ty/#_startPage).

Comment: unfortunately the chat is only steam chat.

Comment: What other chat networks were you thinking about?

Comment: This information is, to the best of my knowledge, correct.